# Problem with Gnuplot 4.4 and TikZ

Tags: latex, gnuplot, tikz

I'm using Gnuplot 4.4, compiled with Lua support. It supposedly has the tikz terminal.

I've successfully compiled my gnuplots to tex using "set terminal tikz". However, when adding this source to my latex document I keep getting the following error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/gnuplot' and I am going t
>   o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

I've included the tikz package in the original tex document. Any ideas?

**EDIT: Solved. See answer bellow.**

Comment: I've eventually moved on to use Tikz with pgfplots, which pretty awesome! http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgfplots/

Answer (score 13):

I didn't give in until I found a solution:

\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}

If you don't have the gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty just get it from the latest gnuplot development snapshot

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I am not allowed to comment here, hence a new answer. The .sty file is not sufficient, you need both of the following files from gnuplot (unfortunately the package is no gnuplot-lua-tikz package at cran):

gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty
gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex

Answer (score 0):

For later happless Fedora users: The package containing this here is `gnuplot-latex`, `dnf` doesn't recognize it as `tex(gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty)`.